# Multiple image and subfigure in my document

Tags: graphics, multiple-files

I have a problem. I want to insert multiple image like this picture. 
But i can't do it

Please help me

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % оролтын кодчилол UTF-8
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel} % lh фонт бүхий T2A кодчилол
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}


\paragraph{Бодлого 1} $SABC$ тетраэдр өгөгдөв. Түүнийг $ M; N;$ ба $P$. Үүнд: $ (SA \ni M; AB \ni N; C \equiv P$

\columnratio{0.3,0.7}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
\begin{leftcolumn}

\underline{Өгсөн нь:} $SABC$ тетраэдр, $ \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \ni M; N; P$, $M \in SA$, $N \in AB$, $P \in C$
\\ \textit{\underline{Байгуулах нь:}} $\phi\textsubscript{огт} = MNP$

\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{b1-1} 
    \caption{\label{fig:}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{b1-2}
    \caption{\label{fig:}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{\label{fig:}}
\end{figure}

\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}


\textit{\underline{Байгуулсан нь:}} ХХХХХ ёсоор $c \equiv P$ тул манай огтлолын дүрс 3 өнцөгт болно.
\\ 1) Эхлээд $ \triangle SAC$ -г авья.
$
\left.\
\begin{array}{rl}
M \in SA \subset \triangle SAC\\
P \in \triangle SAC
\end{array} \right\rbrace
\Rightarrow M; P \in \triangle SAC
$. Нөгөө талаас 
$
\left.\
\begin{array}{rl}
M; P \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт}\\
M; P \in \triangle SAC
\end{array} \right\rbrace
\Rightarrow C_{2}
$ аксиом ёсоор $ [MP] = \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \cap \triangle SAC$ болно.

\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{b1-1} 
    \caption{\label{fig:}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{b1-2}
    \caption{\label{fig:}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{b1-3}
    \caption{\label{fig:}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{\label{fig:}}
\end{figure}

2) Одоо $\triangle SAB $-г авч үзье. Үүнд 
$
\left.\
\begin{array}{rl}
M; N \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт}\\
M; N \in \triangle SAB
\end{array} \right\rbrace
$ гэдгийг харвал $C_{2}$ аксиом ёсоор $[MN]= \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \cap \triangle SAB$ utr ugjyg6
\\3) Одоо $ \triangle ABC$ -г авч үзье. Үүнд мөн 
$
\left.\
\begin{array}{rl}
N; P \in \alpha\textsubscript{огт}\\
N; P \in \triangle ABC
\end{array} \right\rbrace
$ болж $C_{2}$ аксиом ёсоор $[NP] = \alpha\textsubscript{огт} \cap \triangle ANC$ болно.
\\Ингээд $\phi\textsubscript{огт} = MNP$ байгуулагдлаа.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using `.5\textwidth` for each of the three images. 150 % is just too much for one line. Go for `.33`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reduce the width of your `subfigure`s. Right now, you are using three times half of the `\textwidth` which cannot fit on the page.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\newcommand{\myheading}[1]{\noindent\underline{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ogt}{_\text{огт}}

\begin{document}    
    \paragraph{Бодлого 1} $SABC$ тетраэдр өгөгдөв. Түүнийг $M; N;$ ба $P$. Үүнд: $ (SA \ni M; AB \ni N; C \equiv P$ 
    \columnratio{0.3,1}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
        \begin{leftcolumn}          
            \myheading{Өгсөн нь:} $SABC$ тетраэдр, $ \alpha\ogt\ni M; N; P$, $M \in SA$, $N \in AB$, $P \in C$\par 
            \myheading{\emph{Байгуулах нь:}} $\phi\ogt = MNP$           
            \begin{figure}[h]               
                \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}\centering
                    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{b1-1} 
                    \caption{\label{fig:}}
                \end{subfigure}

                \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}\centering
                    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{b1-2}
                    \caption{\label{fig:}}
                \end{subfigure}             
                \caption{\label{fig:}}
            \end{figure}            
        \end{leftcolumn}
        \begin{rightcolumn}         
            \myheading{\emph{Байгуулсан нь:}} ХХХХХ ёсоор $c \equiv P$ тул манай огтлолын дүрс 3 өнцөгт болно.
            \begin{enumerate}[1)]
                \item Эхлээд $ \triangle SAC$ -г авья.
                \[
                \begin{rcases}
                M \in SA \subset \triangle SAC\\
                P \in \triangle SAC
                \end{rcases}
                \Rightarrow M; P \in \triangle SAC
                \] 
                Нөгөө талаас 
                \[
                \begin{rcases}
                M; P \in \alpha\ogt\\
                M; P \in \triangle SAC
                \end{rcases}
                \Rightarrow C_{2}
                \]
                 аксиом ёсоор\\
                 $ [MP] = \alpha\ogt\cap \triangle SAC$ болно.
                 \item Одоо $\triangle SAB $-г авч үзье. Үүнд 
                 \[
                 \begin{rcases}
                 M; N \in \alpha\ogt\\
                 M; N \in \triangle SAB
                 \end{rcases} \]
                  гэдгийг харвал $C_{2}$ аксиом ёсоор $[MN]= \alpha\ogt\cap \triangle SAB$ utr ugjyg6
                 \item Одоо $ \triangle ABC$ -г авч үзье. Үүнд мөн 
                 \[
                 \begin{rcases}
                 N; P \in \alpha\ogt\\
                 N; P \in \triangle ABC
                 \end{rcases}\]
                  болж $C_{2}$ аксиом ёсоор $[NP] = \alpha\ogt\cap \triangle ANC$ болно.
                 \\Ингээд $\phi\ogt = MNP$ байгуулагдлаа.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{rightcolumn}
    \end{paracol}   
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering      
        \begin{subfigure}{.325\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{b1-1} 
            \caption{\label{fig:}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.325\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{b1-2}
            \caption{\label{fig:}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.325\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{b1-3}
            \caption{\label{fig:}}
        \end{subfigure}     
        \caption{\label{fig:}}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]